# Light fixture starts tripping breaker.

Tags: lighting

A light fixture in my foyer was working fine for years.  One day, I turn it on, hear a buzzing noise in the wall, and the breaker trips. I tried a bunch of things, finally discovering the problem doesn't repeat when I replace the fixture (9 60-watt candelabra base bulbs) with a 1 bulb fixture. It wouldn't seem that the 9 bulbs were suddenly too much for the circuit.  So do I likely have a problem with my fixture?

Comment: One way to check the fixture is to do a continuity check with a multimeter and see if the inside wiring may have shorted together. Unfortunately nothing lasts forever.

Answer (score 1):

take the bulbs out of the fixture, if the fixture shows a short it is bad, there is a possibility that one of the lamps is arcing and causing the short, if the fisture wiring shows open with the lamps put them in one at a time untill you find the problem, Yes I know lamps usually burn open but on occasion the filliment post short and can cause this issue,,,